# How does an app verify the installation and usage of another application?

Tags: android, ios

I have come across several apps that have a section that provides ways to earn free in-app credit by interacting with their list of recommending apps. This includes things like `"install and run"` or `"install and complete tutorial"`, and `"install and reach level 10"`.

**My Question:** How does the application track this progress, which I can assume it can do even without being active, since you cannot assume a user will leave it running while getting through another app for an extended period of time. Maybe it inspects achievements attached to it like your Google Play account? Or something else?

Comment: My guess is they implement proprietary APIs for this task in the app that sends the in-app progress information to the original application's server.